# get specific value with Beautiful Soup using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code that extracts all the numbers on the website
if I want to get a specific value how can I do it?
I did this but it doesn't work

```
import urllib
import re
import requests
from bs4 import *

    url = requests.get("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_216543.html")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    sum=0
    tags = soup('span')
    for tag in tags:
        y=str(tag)
        x= re.findall("[0-9]+",y)
        for i in x:
            print (i[1])
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Specific Value"? Can you please show some examples

Comment: As this is homework assignment, just a hint - you need to parse table/tr/td tags and extract name and comments. Don't use regex. Also it's good to post the assignment, i.e. - what do you have to accomplish.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to scrape? all the digits?

Comment: @Jonatan1609 if you open this website http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_216543.html you will see a lot of numbers, if I like to get only the Coby number how can I do that? I did this `print (i[2])` but it doesn't work

Comment: i would recommend to simply itarate over the entire table and keep in a dictionary whatever you need, and then just do `my_dic["Coby"]`.
It is not that hard, but if you get stuck, let me know I will be here to help, I hope.

Comment: @buran The code actually scrapes all the digits, but I want to print a specific number, for example, print (i[2]) it will scrape the number 95

Comment: I understand what you want. That is why I give you a hint how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To get tag "Coby", you can use pass a [custom function to `.find()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
import requests
from bs4 import *

url = requests.get("http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_216543.html")
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")

coby = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name == "tr" and "Coby" in tag.text)

print(coby.get_text(separator=" "))
```

Output:

```
Coby 95
```

Or, to only get the comment, use [`.find_next()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next):

```
print(coby.find_next("span", class_="comments").get_text())
```

Output:

```
95
```